If $f \in L^p(\Omega)$, then $f \in L^q(\Omega)$ for some $q < p + \epsilon$?
Loosely speaking, I would like to know whether membership in some Lebesgue space $L^p$ is stable under small perturbations of the exponent $p$.
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded domain and let $L^p(\Omega)$ denote the Lebesgue space for exponent $1 \leq p < \infty$. Then $L^q(\Omega) \subseteq L^p(\Omega)$  for all $q > p$.
Let us now suppose that $f \in L^p(\Omega)$. Do we have $f \in L^q(\Omega)$ for any $q < p+\epsilon$ for some choice of $\epsilon > 0$?
If not, then I hope to see an example of a function that is "hard" in some $L^p$ space. Most example that I have encountered (e.g., such as powers of the form $\|x\|^{-\gamma}$) leave some wiggle room for the choice of exponent $p$.
If anything more can be said about the possible range of the exponent, even better. Clearly, functions in Sobolev spaces have some flexibility, as per the Sobolev embedding theorem.

The formulation is slightly unclear to me. When you write "for any $q$" do you mean for all $q \in [p, p + \epsilon)$ ? If so it should be sufficient to ask whether $f \in L^p$ implies that $f \in L^{p'}$ for some $p' > p$.

That this is wrong can be seen by Baire's theorem. This is rather a little exercise than research level.

If a proper vector space $V$ of a Banach space $X$ is itself a Banach space with respect to a stronger norm, then $V$ is meagre in $X$. Hence, a countable union of such spaces is meagre, too. Thus, $\bigcup_{q > p} L^q = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} L^{p+\frac{1}{n}}$ is meagre in $L^p$. (Edit: Ok, the other @Jochen was again slightly faster than me. ;-) )

$f(t)=t^{-1}(\log t/2)^{-2}$ on $[0,1]$ belongs yo $L^1$ but not to $L^p$ with $p>1$

@OlivierBégassat: the choice of $\epsilon > 0$ will depend on $f$, as in the formulation of the question. If it belongs to the Lebesgue space with exponent $p+\epsilon$, then it will belong to all Lebesgue spaces with smaller exponent.

@JochenWengenroth: my most sincere apologies for asking.

Presumably you know that for each $q > p$, it is possible to find a function that is in $L^p$ but not in $L^q$ (as $|x|^{-\gamma}$ or the like).  So for each $n$, we may find $f_n \in L^p \setminus L^{p+1/n}$; by replacing $f_n$ with $|f_n|$ we can assume $f_n \ge 0$, and by scaling $f_n$ we can assume $|f_n|_{L^p} \le 2^{-n}$.  Now set $f = \sum_n f_n$.  The sum converges in $L^p$, so we have $f \in L^p$, but $f \ge f_n \notin L^{p+1/n}$ for all $n$, so $f \notin L^q$ for any $q > p$.

@AlpinistKitten No need for apologies. You might consider asking on MathStackExchange before posting such a question here on MO.

Let me add that functions satisfying self-improvement properties like the one considered here are rather important in harmonic analysis (I am thinking of reverse Hölder classes)

Let's also recall an elementary fact: if f is in $L^{p_1}$ and in $L^{p_2}$, it is every $L^p$ in between, by interpolation inequality
